# How to add new ViewState programatically?

Tags: spring-webflow-2

I am trying to find out a way to add new ViewState while performing some action in application. 
Use case : 
I have a spring webflow with 2 static ViewState defined in the flow file. In the the first view there is a UI action that will add one new ViewState. I know, I can add the said ViewState in the flow but this is just a example. I have too many such cases. It was possible in earlier version of Spring webflow. But now ViewState object needs a ViewFactory instance.

How can I add new ViewState in a Flow programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dynamic SPEL doesn't suffice then you'll have to resort to framework hacks.

The FlowModelFlowBuilder.class controls how flows are built/initialized. Extend the FlowModelFlowBuilder.class and override/add to existing methods.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/webflow/engine/builder/model/FlowModelFlowBuilder.html

You'll probably be interested in the createFlow() method. By either overriding, adding to, or studying its functionality to inject your own "dynamic view-states" for predefined flows.

```
createFlow()
Factory method that initially creates the flow implementation during flow builder initialization.
```

Once you've implemented your own FlowBuilder you inject it in your webflow-registery config like this:

```
<webflow:flow-registery id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="someFlowBuilderService">
      <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/**/*-flow.xml"/>
      <webflow:flow-builder class="com.my.package.MyCustomFlowModelFlowBuilder"/>

</webflow:flow-registery>
```

**Disclaimer**: I have personally never done this but the framework does allow you to inject your own custom FlowBuilder impl.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're thinking about this problem incorrectly. You can pass variables into the 'view' attribute of a view-state tag using Spring Expression Language (SPEL) like so

```
<action-state id="determineWhichViewStateToRender">

    <set name="flowScope.dynamicViewState" value="myService.determineWhichViewState()"/>

    <set name="flowScope.modelObj" value="myService.getModelTypeForThisViewState(flowScope.dynamicViewState)"/>
    <transition to="myDynamicViewState"/>
</action-state>


<view-state id="myDynamicViewState" view="#{flowScope.dynamicViewState}/edit" model="modelObj">

..... 

</view-state>
```

and that would achieve a similar effect to "dynamic view-state" that you desire without resorting to frame work hacks.

Also, in the example modelObj can be set to initialized to any object type prior to entering the view-state.

Comment: To rephrase my question, I am trying to add new ViewState while Flow is being launched. I have FlowAction class that will add the required ViewState.

Comment: @Sujay then you will have to hack the framework with your own custom functionality. See new answer. Maybe that is not even what you are trying achieve. I'm really not sure what you are trying to achieve by creating new instances of view-state dynamically. It sounds like a hack or a design problem violating the SRP principle. The purpose of a view-state is to act as a container to define a string key that will map to the predefined view to render and to optionally define a model object to bind to... anything else is NOT a specific goal of a view-state.